# Ignore match in web.config rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

I have and issue where a rule in the web.config is catching something I want it to ignore.

I have:

http://domain.com/video-conferencing-room/australia/australian-capital-territory/barton

Getting picked up by the below rule. I've added  part hoping that would fix it, but no joy. The routing for that

```
 <rule name="video-conferencing-room-country">
        <match url="^video\-conferencing\-room/([0-9a-z- ]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^video\-conferencing\-room/([0-9a-z- ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)" ignoreCase="true"  />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/meeting-rooms/{UrlEncode:{R:1}}" redirectType="Permanent" />              
    </rule>
```

but this condition is stopping urls like this:
http://domain.com/video-conferencing-room/australia

from hitting the rule.

I updated to use {URL}, and :
http://domain.com/video-conferencing-room/australia

now works,

but I still have an issue that

http://domain.com/video-conferencing-room/australia/australian-capital-territory/barton

Is getting rewritten by this rule:

```
 <rule name="video-conferencing-room country state">
        <match url="^video\-conferencing\-room/([0-9a-z- ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^video\-conferencing\-room/([0-9a-z- ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"  />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/meeting-rooms/{UrlEncode:{R:1}}/{UrlEncode:{R:2}}" redirectType="Permanent" />            
    </rule>
```

When I would like it ignored.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not correct, you are setting it with {HTTP_HOST} which is only the host name part, namely in your example domain.com.

Instead try using the {URL} as the input which will include the URL including the video-conferencing... parts.

Comment: thank you, that helps, but I still have an issue. I have editted my original question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$` at the end

```
^video\-conferencing\-room/([0-9a-z- ]+)/([0-9a-z-, ]+)$
```

and you can remove the condition. `$` signifies "end of string".